# Setting stylus variables programmatically

Tags: stylus

I'm working on a project where one stylus file is supposed to spit out a different CSS based on a variable that is defined in a Javascript code. I found [the Javascript API](https://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/js.html) but can't figure out a clean and nice way to set a variable programatically.

Anyone knows how I can set a color variable in Stylus externally using Node.js and get a CSS back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
var stylus = require('stylus');

stylus('body\n  color: some-color')
  .define('some-color', new stylus.nodes.RGBA(128, 128, 128, 1)) // #808080
  .render(function(err, css) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(css);
  });
```

See [lib/nodes/rgba.js](https://github.com/stylus/stylus/blob/master/lib/nodes/rgba.js) and [lib/nodes/hsla.js](https://github.com/stylus/stylus/blob/master/lib/nodes/hsla.js).

I guess you can also use [json bif](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/bifs.html#jsonpath) for your task.